# Element type is invalid: expected a string on react CryptoCompare API

Tags: reactjs, cryptocurrency

I don't know why this error has occurred?

Does someone know this problem?

I've already changed the react-dom of the version that's not working.

My react-dom is react-dom": "^16.13.1",and changed into react-dom": "^16.2.0"

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        import axios from 'axios';
        const NumberFormat = require('react-number-format');


        class App  extends Component {

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
              cryptos: []
            };
          }



      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,IOT&tsyms=USD')
        .then(res => {
          const cryptos = res.data;
          console.log(cryptos);
          this.setState({cryptos: cryptos});
        })
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {Object.keys(this.state.cryptos).map((key) => (
          <div id="crypto-container">
            <NumberFormat value={this.state.cryptos[key].USD} displayType={'text'} decimalPrecision={2} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPa0X.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbfAk.png)

Comment: post the screenshot which shows error

Comment: @O.o I added the  screenshot. Could you confirm it?

Comment: I can't understand this problem at all. check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-moon-ryvd6?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @O.o I did copy your code but it didn't work. Also, I looked up another folder whether the problem or not. And then, there has some difference which is   "document.getElementById('root')" that has my index.js file.

Comment: How are they different?